# How to deduct 1 Hour and 30 Minute from the time in html form?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I deduct 1 hour and 30 minutes from the time given in the html form using Javascript?

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function calculate(){
        var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;
    }
        
    </script>
    </head>

    Time:<input id="time" type="time" name="task_time" />
    <button id="calc" onclick="calculate()">Get Time</button>

    <p id="demo">Test</p>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember, a time field's value will be a 6 digit colon separated value. There might be a better way to do this using moment.js, but in pure JavaScript, you can do:

```
var time = ...;
var parts = time.split(":");
var now = new Date(); // Create a Date object
now.setHours(parseInt(parts[0])); 
now.setMinutes(parseInt(parts[1]) - 90); //subtract 90 minutes
now.setSeconds(parseInt(parts[2]));
```

Comment: `input[type="time"]` contains 2 segments by default - hours and minutes. Seconds are shown when you use the `step` attribute. In this case a check should be added when accessing `parts[2]`.

Comment: @zhulien Thank you for your comment / correction... Useful!

Comment: I guess it is useable for now

Comment: @DavidLee If this has resolved your question, please click the check mark next to the answer